# How to enable Message Pack protocol in SignalR Azure Functions?

Tags: signalr, azure-functions, signalr-hub, msgpack

We have an Azure Function supporting a SignalR hub leveraging Azure SignalR Services to publish messages to connected signalR clients. We'd like to enable MessagePack protocol in the function but we could not find any documentation or guidelines to tell how to do it. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly Message Pack protocol is initiated and used when the client app negotiates with the function. [Further information can be found here](https://github.com/anthonychu/serverless-draw/commit/8dd41aac3b2f009ef014980a3bf4bb41de6c1569).